# Writing a filter in Opencover to include only one assembly

Tags: opencover

I am using OpenCover to analyse the code coverage of my project. I am using MSTest to write UNIT Tests. I want to analyze the code coverage of a particular assembly and only that assembly.I want to write a filter the same.
Basically the filter should look exclude everything from my solution except that assembly which I intend to do code coverage on.

I wrote a filter like this.But it doesnot seem to be working

```
   -filter:"-[*]* +[NameOfAssembly]*"
```

Comment: Have you tried `-filter:"+[NameOfAssembly]*"`?

Comment: @ful-stackz you are correct - you should put that as an answer :)